# Naive Python issue "No module named 'local_settings'"

Tags: python, django

I am using django as backend and trying to segregate the production settings and local settings by following steps [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/using-separate-settings-files-in-a-django-project-for-local-development-and-production-a-6a6866866d01). I am facing following error when I do `./manage.py makemigrations`,
`from local_settings import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'local_settings'`

Following is what my **settings.py** looks like,

```
# Set DEBUG based on the environment
DEBUG = True
if DEBUG:
    from local_settings import *
else:
    from prod_settings import *
```

**local_settings.py** and **production_settings.py** reside in the same directory as settings.py. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `from .local_settings import *`  The dot means "in the same directory as the current module"

Comment: @JohnGordon _"The dot means "in the same directory as the current module"_: Ooh, you've opened a big can of worms...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a structure like this:

```
main.py
 - settings
   - settings.py
   - local_settings.py
   - prod_settings.py
```

Then `import local_settings` will try and access `local_settings.py` at the same (root project) level as `main.py`

You can either do a relative import, like this:
`from .local_settings import *`

Relative imports can also work on parent paths, so if `local_settings.py` was at the same level as `main.py`, but you were importing from a file within the `settings` module, you could do `from ..local_settings`.

Or a full path import, like this: `from settings.local_settings import *`

If the full path import doesn't work, it's likely your `PYTHONPATH` setting that is incorrect.

Also, while settings might be considered an exception, note that `import *` is generally not advised.

My personal preference is always to use full path imports, and never to do `import *`. Remember, `explicit is better than implicit` !!